# Replacing element with another when dragged into an area with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring this one out - if it's even possible to do so without a much deeper knowledge of javascript.

Basically, I am using jQueryUI to make an element draggable. When this element is dragged within a certain area (using position), I want it to turn into another element (both elements are divs). The problem when I do this with `replace()` is that the new element doesn't have the draggable property on it, and its position is that of the original element's position before the drag. Heck, I can't even get it to be draggable, even with liveDraggable which I found here on SO.

I could kind of get around this by replacing some CSS classes and the contents of the elements, but somehow it feels like too much code would be needed for such as "simple" purpose.

Here's my current code with class switching:

```
$( ".toolbar-plugin").draggable({
    drag: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("position", "abolute");
        var pluginType = $(this).attr("id");
        var offsetYPos = parseInt(ui.offset.top);
        var offsetXPos = parseInt(ui.offset.left);
        if(offsetYPos > 80) {
            $(this).removeClass("toolbar-plugin ui-widget-header"); 
            $(this).addClass("floating-plugin ui-widget-content");
        }
    }
});
```

I've seen things like this done on the drop event, but I really need for it to work while dragging, and not lose "control" over the drag.

Comment: Not an answer, but there'a typo. Change `$(this).css("position", "abolute");` to `$(this).css("position", "absolute");`

Comment: Oh thanks! I was wondering why that didn't work :)

Comment: cant you replace the contents only rather than the whole element itself?

Comment: As I said, I can, just like I can change the CSS. The problem is that I'm trying to replace simple elements (a div with one word an an image) into one that can be much more complex, including forms and a high number of elements. Replacing that simple div with the complex one with a single function (even if it has to be a plugin) would be much easier than to add all the elements every time. I'll keep it as a last resort, but I'm wondering if there isn't a more elegant solution.